# How to record video?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to access camera to record video to upload, but have come across many articles which states that there is no access for third party to record video. Here's the link:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/74190/452090.aspx 
http://pocketnow.com/windows-phone/no-video-camera-access-for-windows-phone-7-developers

Is it true? If not how do I use camera to record video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Mango feature with Raw Camera Data. 
Basically, all you need is in following article: 
http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib

The only difference is that in method *ScanPreviewBuffer* author scans QR code, and you should store those images and then make a video from them.

That's how I would do that task

Comment: And this is maybe not the best way. Article in MSDN covers this topic better, as @Shawn Kendrot suggests

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck because MSDN has a [great article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on how to do this! You can also [download the complete sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226290) code. You can see more samples from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Two of the three links are dead.

Comment: Next time I'll make sure Microsoft keeps their links alive

Comment: LOL. Good luck with that! The way MS breaks their links you'd think they were getting paid to!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true?

It used to be true back when those articles were written. The earlier version of WP7, before Mango, did not support any APIs to access the camera (the best you could do was launch the camera app itself I think). As of v7.1 you have access to it as Shawn and Alex have said.